# не работает медиа запрос

Tags: html, css, gulp

Подскажите пожалуйста собираю проект галпом, медиа-запросы работают во всех браузерах кроме гугл хрома в чем может быть причина ? 
вот мой файл галпа

```js
var gulp      = require('gulp'),
  sass      = require('gulp-sass'),
  browserSync   = require('browser-sync'),
  concat     = require('gulp-concat'),
  uglify    = require('gulp-uglifyjs'),
  cssnano     = require('gulp-cssnano'),
  rename     = require('gulp-rename'),
  del       = require('del'),
  imagemin    = require('gulp-imagemin'),
  pngquant    = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
  cache      = require('gulp-cache'),
  uncss      = require('gulp-uncss'),
  autoprefixer  = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
  bourbon = require('node-bourbon');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.sass')
  .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: require('node-bourbon').includePaths
        }).on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 version', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'],{cascade: true}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
  .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
  return gulp.src([
   'app/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
   'app/libs/pushy/js/pushy.min.js',
  ])
  .pipe(concat('libs.min.js'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'))
});

gulp.task('css-libs', function(){
  return gulp.src([
   'app/css/libs/normalize.css',
   'app/css/libs/pushy.css'
  ])
  .pipe(concat('libs.min.css'))
  .pipe(cssnano())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
});

gulp.task('css-style', function(){
  return gulp.src('app/css/style.css')
  .pipe(uncss({
   html: ['app/**/*.html']
  }))
  .pipe(cssnano())
  .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
});


gulp.task('browser-sync', function(){
 browserSync({
  server: { 
   baseDir: 'app'
  },
 }); 
});

gulp.task('clean', function(){
  return del.sync('dist');
});

gulp.task('clear', function(){
  return cache.clearAll();
});

gulp.task('img', function(){
  return gulp.src('app/img/**/*')
  .pipe(cache(imagemin({
   interlaced: true,
   progressive: true,
   svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
   une: [pngquant()]
  })))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'))
});


gulp.task('watch',['browser-sync','css-libs','sass','css-style','scripts'], function(){
 gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.sass',['sass']);
 gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js' , browserSync.reload);
 gulp.watch('app/*.html' , browserSync.reload);
 gulp.watch('app/**/*.css' , browserSync.reload);
});

// таск который построит нам в папке дист все исходные файлы
gulp.task('build', ['clean', 'img', 'sass', 'css-style','css-libs', 'scripts'], function(){
 
 var builCss = gulp.src([
  'app/css/style.min.css',
  'app/css/libs.min.css',
 ])
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
 
 var buildFonts = gulp.src('app/fonts/**/*')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'));

 var buildJs = gulp.src('app/js/**/*')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
 
 var buildHtml = gulp.src('app/*.html')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

 
});
```

Comment: вопрос снят забыл добавить <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">